# NoMethodError in Static_pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nomethoderror

I'm getting a no method error in my Static_pages#home:

undefined method `exists?' for Registry

```
 The little code I'm using it in is:

 <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.registry.exists? %>

 <%= link_to "Show My Registry", current_user.registry %>

 <% else %>

 <%= link_to "Create a new registry", new_registry_path %>

 <% end %>
```

Should I add something to the controller for home?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to the controller, no--it's complaining about the `registry` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exists?` method is a class method. You have to either do:

```
Registry.exists?  # Is there any registery?
```

or specify the id for the Registry:

```
Registry.exist?(current_user.registry_id)
```

Here is some reference:

```
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks - I used it and got the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

In the end this worked:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && Registry.exists?(current_user.registry) %>
```

Comment: Great! If my answer helped, then please accept(feel free to edit and add your comments at the end).